# Using .format() in Python to allign a mix of variables and characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, string.format

I'm trying to learn how to use Python's .format() to make my console output for a test I'm writing look more readable but I'm not quite wrapping my head around it yet.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
print('({:d}/{:d}) {} {} {} {}'.format(test, num_tests, *item))
```

It prints out what I want it to nicely enough but I want to align these different fields so that they always line up no matter how many digits something is.  For example, my current output would look something like this:

```
(9/800) item1 item2 item3 item4
(10/800) item1 item2 item3 item4
```

Is there a way I can rewrite my format so that it looks like this instead?

```
 (9/800) item1 item2 item3 item4
(10/800) item1 item2 item3 item4
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you know ahead of time the maximum possible size of a particular field, which I assume isn't the case because you say "no matter how many digits...". Suppose the line after these two says "(99999999999/800)". Python can't go back and rewrite the lines it already printed to add more spaces. (well maybe it could if you're using `curses` or similar, but not every console is going to support that)

Comment: So I can safely assume that the first number will never be more digits than the second.  I'm also fine with assuming that num_tests will never be more than say 5 digits.  I don't need it to be completely flexible.

Comment: If you know the maximum size at compile time, you can manually specify the width in the format string: `print('({:3d}/...`. Setting the first field's with to the length of the second field at run time would be a little trickier.

Comment: That works pretty well other than the potentially big space between the open parenthesis and the first number.  I'm the only one who'll ever see this so it doesn't matter much but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a custom function and set the [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) for setting the length in which text it to be wrapped. Your custom function can be as:

```
def my_print(test, num_tests, *item):
    width = 8 
    test = '({:d}/{:d})'.format(test, num_tests).rjust(width)
    items = ''.join(str(i).rjust(width) for i in item)
    print test + items
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_print(9, 800, 'yes', 'no', 'hello')
 (9/800)     yes      no   hello
```

---

If it is must to do it via `str.format()`, you may create custom function to add padding as:

```
def my_print(test, num_tests, *item):
    test = '{0: >10}'.format('({:d}/{:d})'.format(test, num_tests))
    items = ''.join('{0: >6}'.format(i) for i in item)
    print test + items
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_print(9, 800, 'yes', 'no', 'hello')
   (9/800)   yes    no hello
```

Check [String Format Specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) document for the list of all formatting options.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do it with .format() but this will do fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh it never occurred to me that I could format a format.  That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print('({:>3}/{}) {} {} {} {}'.format(test, num_tests, *item))
```

Example:

```
>>> print('({:>3}/{}) {} {} {} {}'.format(0, 800, 1, 2, 3, 4))
(  0/800) 1 2 3 4
>>> print('({:>3}/{}) {} {} {} {}'.format(10, 800, 1, 2, 3, 4))
( 10/800) 1 2 3 4
>>> print('({:>3}/{}) {} {} {} {}'.format(100, 800, 1, 2, 3, 4))
(100/800) 1 2 3 4
```

Other example:

```
>>> print('({:>3}/{}) {:>12} {:>12} {:>12} {:>12}'.format(1, 800, 'Python', 'Hello', 'World', '!'))
(  1/800)       Python        Hello        World            !
>>> print('({:>3}/{}) {:>12} {:>12} {:>12} {:>12}'.format(100, 800, 'I', 'Love', 'Python', '!'))
(100/800)            I         Love       Python            !
```

Or

```
>>> print('({:03d}/{}) {:>12} {:>12} {:>12} {:>12}'.format(12, 800, 'I', 'Love', 'Python', '!'))
(012/800)            I         Love       Python            !
```

Comment: That looks pretty good.  Just wondering if there's a simple way to remove the extra spaces after the open parenthesis.

Comment: New example, you can use: {:>3}  -> (012/800)

Comment: {:03d} -> (012/800)